# SQL warning: mysql_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be string

Tags: php, sql

I am using following query:

```
$search = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE username LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($query)."%' OR name LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($query)."%' ORDER BY timestamp");
```

where $query is words user search for. I am getting following warning:

Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be string

The table has username as varchar. Is this what problem is? Or can anyone please help me if they know what is causing this warning?

Comment: What is `$query`? My guess is that it isn't a string...

Comment: `var_dump( $query )` see what you get.

Comment: what says `var_dump($query)`? I'm sure it's not a string.

Comment: @develroot - where should i put this statement(var_dump( $query )) at? In the php script?

Comment: I think i know what the problem is. query has value of: Resource id #19
I am not sure where it is getting that value from i will have to look.

Comment: @ken Can you post the code where you set `$query`?

Comment: Here it is: function search() {
    var query = $("#query").val().replace(/^\s*/, "").replace(/\s*$/, "");
    if (!query.match(/\w/) || query.length < 3) {
        $("#query").addClass("highlightRed");
        return;
    }
    $("#query").removeClass("highlightRed");
    getResults($("#searchtype").val(),
               $("#query").val(), 1);
};

Comment: @lonesomeday - I am confused as i have not entered anything in the query textbox as of yet. But it is still showing warning even before entering anything. I dont know where it is getting that resource id from.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Warning: mysql_fetch_* expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11674312/warning-mysql-fetch-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-error)

Comment: Be aware: the `mysql_xxx()` functions are deprecated and not recommended for use. If at all possible, you should switch to the `mysqli_xx()` functions or the PDO library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$query` (the VARIABLE) is no string. That's the simple answer that the error message already told you.

Fix that. Listen to what the error message says. It doesn't speak about the query itself, but the /variable/.

Answer (score 1):

If $query is supplied by user input, you should check to ensure that it has a value:

```
if(!is_null($query)) {
....
}
```

Since you don't show much code, it could be that your assignment **to** $query is failing resulting in $query being NULL. I don't think that error is specific to a string value *type*, it's only saying there's nothing there!

Answer (score 0):

`$query` is probably not string (it could be bool or simply integer)
You have probably some string BEFORE this line

try to do this before your query

```
$query = (string) $query
```

It should work then as it's forced to convert $query to the string

Comment: I think it would be better to work out why `$query` isn't *already* a string.

Comment: @lonesomeday: because it's maybe intval()ed or something? My answer solves it in any case, and it's point of this question

Comment: @lonesomeday: added more info

Comment: As the update to the question says, `$query` is a resource, which can't be converted to a string with `(string)`.  In any case, I think `mysql_real_escape_string` can cope with integers internally.

Comment: @lonesomeday: $query is a resource? Where is that written?